# force no smiley in markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I wrote a comment in GitHub, quoting tslint result:

> ERROR: packages/core/directives/map.ts:100:1 - trailing whitespace

GitHub saw :100: and converted it into a

How do I tell GitHub not to process smileys in the next line or block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1153) with some workaround

You can use [backticks](https://github.github.com/gfm/#code-spans) to render your error message as inline code snippet:

```
`ERROR: packages/core/directives/map.ts:100:1 - trailing whitespace`
```

Or you can use [numeric character reference syntax](https://github.github.com/gfm/#decimal-numeric-character-references) `&#XXXX;` to add a [Zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) char between `:` and `100`:

```
ERROR: packages/core/directives/map.ts:&#8203;100:1 - trailing whitespace
```